# What happens to Expedia Pay later non-refundable booking in case of no show?

Tags: expedia

When you choose the 'Pay later' option on Expedia to book a hotel, you are given a certain deadline to cancel free of cost? Now when you cancel post this deadline or end up 'no show' how will the hotel recover this amount from you?

I suppose they can do so if you have used your credit card for guarantee, but Expedia allows you to use debit card for such bookings too. Recently debit card transactions have a Mastercard/Visa SecureCode or SMS OTP system to make payment. So in case of a 'no show', just the debit card and CVV number is useless for the hotels to recover the cancellation charge. What happens in such circumstance? Does the hotel or Expedia just 'forget about it'?

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50631/how-does-booking-com-enforce-cancellation-fees-when-booking-without-a-credit-car

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to process a credit or debit card transaction.

One of them is an offline transaction without the customer being present. For this, the 16-digit number plus the CVV are sufficient and the SecurCode system is *not* used. So you can be charged in such a case.

Also, Expedia or the hotel may pre-authorize the charge before your arrival. In such a case, you will not be charged ahead of time, but the hotel is sure that the charge can be made. Again, the CC number and the CVV are sufficient for this.

Comment: You don't even need the CVV. Amazon for example is known not to ask for the CVV in many cases. Of course that means they are on the hook for most fraud but it seems to be worth it.

Answer (score 2):

They do not forget about your booking. You will be charge if you're a no show. If you cancel after the free period, you'll b charged a fee. If it states it non-refundable booking or deposit, then you lose the price of your booking or deposit for the trouble of not cancelling.

It is very easy to cancel with Expedia. You can do it on their website. I haven't booked with hotel in awhile and I've never cancelled.

I usually put a reminder in my phone or on the calendar to remind me of cancellation or bookings. I hope this helps.