# What happens if you don't pay booking.com cancellation fees?

Tags: hotels, cancellations, booking.com

What happens if you book two hotels through booking.com and reach only one hotel without cancelling the other booking?

Would that hotel charge include cancellation charge of first hotel?

**UPDATE**

Not sure in case of no show. However if you cancel your booking, booking.com will try to charge you immediately even **without CVV**.

Comment: Booking.com is allowed to charge you, as you have commited to booking a room which could not be cancelled.

Comment: Yes but it won't ask for the CVV while deducting the amount. So if one thinks he/she will cancel the cancelling operation once it asks for CVV it may deduct without CVV.

Comment: Merchants do not need the CVV to process a card payment.  The only consequence is they pay a net higher fee to do so.

Comment: In fact, Booking.com might charge you actually. This applies if you pay with PayPal, Sofortbanking e.g., as well if you want to pay with a credit card, whilst the property only accepts cash, in case the accommodation accepts this kind of payment. Normally, the charges are done by the property and in any case they are subject to their policies. Regards

Answer (score 6):

Hotels don't have access to information about your bookings at other hotels and can't charge you for cancelling your stay at the first hotel. Likewise Booking.com itself doesn't charge customers and only passes on credit card information to the hotels.

Therefore it will be up to the first hotel to try and charge your card after you fail to show up. If the stay was booked without a credit card, hotels [usually won't bother](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50631/how-does-booking-com-enforce-cancellation-fees-when-booking-without-a-credit-car) with trying to charge you the cancellation fee.

Comment: I believe booking.com and similar sites will charge customers directly, at least sometimes. These sites often charge your card themselves and give the hotel a "virtual credit card number" belonging to the company which is used for your reservation. The hotel can't see how much you actually paid and has no control over your reservation without going through the booking site. Expedia [does this routinely](https://frzferoz.wordpress.com/2015/04/01/expedia-virtual-card-did-it-changed-how-travelvacation-industry-worked/). The exact details depend on the booking site, hotel, and cancellation rules.

Comment: @ZachLipton Booking.com never charges cards directly, even in the case of a no-show. Expedia is different, since they ask for pre-payment.

Comment: Yes, right, only hotel charges, booking.com does not.

Comment: I made a reservation earlier this week for one night via booking.com and was neither asked for payment _nor_ for payment info.  So perhaps the hotels are offered different types of listings?  Of course I did have to pay on arrival.

Comment: @WGroleau I've even seen different terms for the same hotel. Pay a higher rate for no prepayment and no cancellation fees, or pay a much lower rate with less favorable terms.

Answer (score 2):

*Most* times, cancellations fees are not paid, *they are charged*. This is why even if you have to pay on check-out, you are asked for a credit card number, although some hotels reservations do not ask for a card, in which case they have no way to charge you.

For most reservations, when you press the *Cancel* button on Booking.com, any applicable fee will be charged to your card immediately. If instead, you do nothing and not show up, either Booking.com or the hotel will charge you something which could be the value of the entire stay or the first night, again this depends on the hotel policy.

Once the charge is on your credit card, then you will have to pay the balance unless you dispute the transaction with your credit card company. Since your booking was subject to certain rules, there is little chance of them agreeing in your favor.

As per [another question on this site](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50631/how-does-booking-com-enforce-cancellation-fees-when-booking-without-a-credit-car), if you did not provide a credit card, it seems that you generally won't be charged but a hotel could send you a bill the the cancellation fee if they were so inclined.