# What happens if I reserve at Booking.com a non-refundable apartment and guarantee it with a debit card with zero balance?

Tags: payment-cards, cancellations, booking.com

Will the reservation be confirmed?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we do not give advice on breaking the law and this is fraud.

Comment: @chx This isn't necessarily advice on breaking the law. OP maybe doesn't need the card anymore, apart from the reservation, and doesn't want to pay the recharge commission unnecessarily.

Comment: Related question: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/40586/ive-booked-a-hotel-on-booking-com-using-an-empty-debit-card-can-the-hotel-stil?rq=1

Comment: @chx Or perhaps OP plans to load the card up before staying but doesn't have the money in the card's account yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I've booked a hotel on Booking.com using an empty debit card. Can the hotel still enforce their no-show/cancellation charge?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/40586/ive-booked-a-hotel-on-booking-com-using-an-empty-debit-card-can-the-hotel-stil)

Comment: I do not see how come this is considered fraud. I have done this once with full intention to stay at the hotel (in which I stayed evetually, was pretty good, thanks for asking) however I had some bank account issues back at the time and had to try it. As my answer suggests, everything worked out for the best eventually.

This is obviously a matter of perspective

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After reading the [Booking.com: Terms and conditions](https://www.booking.com/content/terms.en-gb.html), I doubt if your method works since I believe Booking.com or the hotel might try to charge your debit card the full amount upon confirming your booking.

> For certain (non-refundable) rates or special offers, please note that Suppliers may require that payment is made upfront by wire transfer (if available) or by credit card, and therefore **your credit card may be pre-authorised or charged** (sometimes without any option for refund) **upon making the reservation**.

Comment: Booking.com never charges your card, but the hotel might do it.

Comment: This is really depends on hotel. 4 star hotel in New York didn't charge anything until we were there, and they've asked hat do I like to use. Same was in small motel in Miami. However, other motel charged in one day the card I've provided.

Comment: @VMAtm Since the OP is making a non-refundable booking and the T&C already stated that upfront payment might be required, it is possible that OP could fail to secure the booking in this case. For other free-cancellation booking, you are correct.

Comment: I have had a reservation on my credit card for two full months (about 4 months to 2 months before the stay) for the full amount, on a 'free cancelation' hotel booking. Other times I did not get charged, or a reservation, at all for the same hotel with the same booking site. It was not a charge, but it would have affected me if I had wanted to use the full credit amount of the card.

Answer (score 6):

They will contact you soon enough explaining that your card is not valid for this type of booking, and they will request that you would use another.

It happened to me once.
It happens also when there's free cancelation

Answer (score 5):

What's your aim? To book a reservation with a minimal amount of money? Then the reservation could be created, with a small authorization check as @Tom said. However, as we are speaking about the non refundable rooms, at some moment, usually about a 24 hours before reservation starts, hotel do another transaction for a whole sum or first day payment, and, if it fails, they may deny you to enter before you pay it. Also, you may be asked to present the card from a reservation.

Comment: I want reserve apartment through booking that have to be paid in advance by 42days before, as they mention at that time card can be charge anytime, but I prefer pay cash, so if I use debit card with zero balance for reserve it will be possible accepted the reservation?

Comment: If they attempt to authorize the transaction and your card is declined (which is what will likely happen), they might contact you to arrange for another means of payment. They might also not guarantee your reservation anymore, as they would prefer to offer it to someone else with a valid method of payment, and you could wind up with no place to stay. You'd have to contact the service find out whether they even will accept cash, as I suspect that may not be an option (among other reasons, booking.com wants to take their cut of the fee out of your payment).

Comment: @Nika, in general, they will charge you not in advance, but right before reservation starts. You should contact the hotel for that

Answer (score 3):

In the UK at least, this payment will probably be put through.  If the payment is several hundred pounds, the bank may refuse the transaction, and will probably put a security block on the card.  If it's £50 or so though, almost certainly they'll allow it.

Your account will then be overdrawn by the cost of the deposit, and you will be charged for setting up an unagreed overdraft.  The charges these days are less than they used to be, but you will still be charged.  And of course you'll incur interest on the amount you're overdrawn *and* the charges, for as long as you're overdrawn.

In short, it's not a smart move.

Comment: What if OP uses a prepaid anonymous card?

Comment: @JonathanReez those are very rare in the UK.