# Hotel reservation on booking.com using debit card

Tags: hotels, cancellations, booking.com

I booked a hotel for my Mum's birthday. I put my Visa debit card info in, thinking it would work, but I received an email saying it was invalid and I need to give a valid card within the next 24 hours to guarantee my stay.

As I don't have a credit card, will I still be charged for cancellation? !

[image]

Comment: Have you contacted your bank and asked why the charge was rejected?

Comment: Well the card I gave wasn't a credit card. I don't own a credit card

Comment: That may or may not be the problem. The bank will know.

Comment: Will I still be charged if I don't manage to sort it within the next 24 hours?

Comment: There is evidence on this web site of debit cards being accepted. See [I've booked a hotel on Booking.com using an empty debit card. Can the hotel still enforce their no-show/cancellation charge?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/40586/19560). Web sites often say "credit card" when they will also accept debit cards.

Comment: There is no general problem with using a debit card on booking.com, I do this regularly (UK debit card, staying in the UK and elsewhere).

Comment: You can't get charged anything, if they don't have your creditcard. But I will for sure just write them an email to confirm the cancellation.

Comment: I just booked a hotel in London using a UK debit card as well. But this has happened to me before and I had to use a (luckily) different card.

Answer (score 4):

You can use debit or credit cards in the booking.com which is mentioned in their terms and conditions.

https://www.booking.com/content/terms.en-gb.html

> Payment is safely processed from your **credit/debit card** or bank
>   account to the bank account of the accommodation provider through a
>   third party payment processor.

Call your bank to see why they blocked the charge. I am afraid only your bank can sort this out.

Answer (score 2):

This has happened to me twice while using my credit card to book through Booking.com (both times were, coincidentally or not, in Paris). You can either contact the hotel to confirm your reservation or contact Booking.com who will try to work something out with the hotel for you.

As for being charged for cancellation: I don't think you need to worry about that, if you don't do anything your reservation will simply be canceled and you won't be charged.

Answer (score 2):

Several possibilities with your card issue:

- Could you have made a mistake when you typed in the card number?
- Was there enough money in your account to cover the charge plus a bit more?
- Does your card have a single POS sale limit (ie max of ‎£200 purchase)?
- Are you not in the UK and don't make global purchases very often?

But as for being charged for a cancellation, you have not yet guaranteed the booking and likely Booking.com will automatically cancel your reservation due to lack of your guarantee.  They can't charge you for an unconfirmed booking cancellation they make.